# array_search returns NULL/blank

Tags: php, arrays, search

I have such array

```
<?php
$a = array(
    "apple"=>"uniqid1",
    "apple"=>"uniqid2",
    "apple"=>"uniqid3",
    "bannana"=>"uniqid4"
    );

echo array_search("uniqid1", $a, true);

?>
```

When I search for "uniqid4" it returns "bannana" (all good)

But when I search for "uniqid1" it returns blank/NULL (I know there are duplicates - but array is as it is)

My question is :

How to search for "uniqid1" or "uniqid2" or "uniqid3" and get "apple" everytime?

based on first to answers:

If i reverse array:

```
$a=array(

"uniqid1"=>"apple",
"uniqid2"=>"apple",
"uniqid3"=>"apple",
"uniqid4"=>"bannana");
```

how to search `uniqid3`or `uniqid2` or `uniqid1`

```
echo array_search("uniqid3",$a, true);
```

and get `apple` everytime?

Comment: You say the array is as it is.  Can we see a sample of the actual array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ArSeN said, **you cannot use the same apple index multiple times**. In doing so, PHP will understand that only the third exists, the first two will be ignored because they use the same key.

Maybe there is a way to make this work, and it would be by changing keys and values, then keys would become values.

The code would look like this:

```
<?php

$array = array(
    'uniqid1' => 'apple',
    'uniqid2' => 'apple',
    'uniqid3' => 'apple',
    'uniqid4' => 'bannana'
);

echo $array['uniqid1'];
echo '<br>';
echo $array['uniqid2'];
echo '<br>';
echo $array['uniqid3'];
echo '<br>';
echo $array['uniqid4'];

?>
```

**Output**

> apple 
> apple 
> apple
>  bannana

As you can see, keys have become values, and it is now possible to obtain these values by indicating their index

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the same index multiple times. Defining it multiple times will overwrite the value at that index, which leads to only the last value that is assigned (`uniqid3` in this case) still remaining.

You can check this like so:

```php
$a=array(

"apple"=>"uniqid1",
"apple"=>"uniqid2",
"apple"=>"uniqid3",
"bannana"=>"uniqid4");

var_dump($a);
```

And you will see there are actually only two entries:

```
array(2) {
  ["apple"]=>
  string(7) "uniqid3"
  ["bannana"]=>
  string(7) "uniqid4"
}
```

If you flip the values (use the values as keys and vice versa) this would work fine and you could search for apple then.

Comment: just tried and  it returns NULL for  everything <?php
$a=array(

"uniqid1"=>"apple",
"uniqid2"=>"apple",
"uniqid3"=>"apple",
"uniqid4"=>"bannana");

echo array_search("uniqid3",$a, true);

?>

Comment: @Rob You can not use the same index, when you do it, PHP will ignore the first two and will only recognize the third. If you try to search for **uniqid3** you'll see it is working, but if you search for **uniqid2** or **uniqid1** it'll not work, PHP will ignore the first two because it has the same index as the third, only the third will work.

Comment: @Rob `array_search()` searches for a value in the array, not for a key. To access an entry by key, you don't even need that and can just access it with the key, like so: `$a['uniqid1']`

Answer (score 0):

this is your array

```
$a=array(
"apple"=>"uniqid1",
"apple"=>"uniqid2",
"apple"=>"uniqid3",
"bannana"=>"uniqid4");
```

it is exactly like this array:

```
$a=array(
"apple"=>"uniqid3",
"bannana"=>"uniqid4");
```

you are overwriting "apple" 2 more times.
so it's logical if you search for `uniqid1` and `uniqid2` you will get null, but if you search for `uniqid3` and `uniqid4` you will get an answer.

after you defined an array, you give `"apple" => "uniqid1"` but in the next line, you overwrite it an give `"apple"` another value, `"apple" => "uniqid2"`

after that you give third value to `"apple"` again `"apple" => "uniqid3"`

so `"apple"` has this value: `"uniqid3"`

so `"uniqid1"` and `"uniqid2"` do not exist in your array any more.